# CSS repeat pattern with linear gradient

Tags: html, css, repeat

I'm on my first approach with photoshop patterns.I'm buildin a webpage where I want to use my pattern to give a nice effect to my webpage background.

The **pattern I found is 120x120 px**

[image]

If I was done here I should use this css:

```
background-imag:url(mypattern.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
```

But Im not done.Id like to **add to my page's background a linear gradient(dir=top/down col=light-blue/green) with the pattern fill layer on top of it, with blending mode=darken **.

This is the final effect:

[image]

I come to the point.

**QUESTION:**
Combining linear vertical-gradient effect and my 120x120 pattern is it possible to find a pattern that I could use to repeat itself endlessly both vertical and horizontal??which is a common solution in this case?

Hope It's clear

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1):

or you can use background gradinent css3

```
body { background: url('pattern.jpg') repeat;}
#container {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

to make it work in IE lte 7 add:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#FFFFFFFF', EndColorStr='#00FFFFFF')
```

color is provided in `#aarrggbb` format, where aa=alpha(transparency), rest like normal hex color.

Comment: is this method cross-browser??

Comment: @luca, yes with exception for IE lte 7

Answer (score 0):

Apply

```
html{
    background: url('mypattern.jpg') repeat;
}
body{
    background: url('gradient.png') repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

where gradient.png is your white gradient which becomes transparent to it's bottom.

Comment: my gradient is not white..Is light blue/green.In photoshop I added the pattern fill on a layer with darken blending mode. is it your still a valid solution?=)

Comment: It doesn't matter. The only important thing about gradient is that it should be in .png format (there are other suitable formats, but png has more advanteges) and it should be partially transparent (more at the top and less in the bottom)

Comment: i dont think i understood.In photoshop the effect is done by two layers:the bottom layer is the gradient(light blu to green) and top layer is the pattern fill with blending mode=darken..

Answer (score 0):

Dis will work, bg pattern with linear or radial gradient:

```
background-image: url(images/pattern.png),  -webkit-radial-gradient(30% 40%, rgb(20,150,224), rgb(0,0,0));
    background-image: url(images/pattern.png),  -moz-radial-gradient(30% 40%, rgb(20,150,224), rgb(0,0,0));
    background-image: url(images/pattern.png),  -ms-radial-gradient(30% 40%, rgb(20,150,224), rgb(0,0,0));
    background-image: url(images/pattern.png),  -o-radial-gradient(30% 40%, rgb(20,150,224), rgb(0,0,0));
    background-image: url(images/pattern.png),  radial-gradient(circle at 30% 40%, rgb(20,150,224), rgb(0,0,0));
```